# CSS: How to make child element take up remaining space in a list item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the child element of a list-item take up the remaining width, but the problem is the list item's marker is getting in the way, so I can't just make the width 100%. Any ideas on how to fix this? I wish list-style-position: outside did not put the marker outside of the container, otherwise that could work.

```css
.list-item {
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: list-item
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  background: gray;
 }
 
 .child {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="child">
      <span>Test</span>
      <span>Test</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome here? Do you want the `list-marker` to essentially stay on the same line as the text? So you get a list item with the marker and then your `span` elements on the same line?

Comment: @disinfor yes, I want them all on the same line.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a `list-item` here? Since you have a `<div>` and not a `<ul>` - does this really need to be a list?

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```css
      .list-item {
        list-style-position: inside;
        display: list-item;
      }

      .container {
        width: 500px;
        background: gray;
      }

      .child {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
```

```html
 
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <ul>
          <div class="child">
        <li class="list-item">
            <span>Test</span>
            <span style="margin:10vw;">Test</span>
        </li>
             </div>
 </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

edit as @David Thomas point that explain will we help ful so it is here now by edit

1.replaced the " < div>" element with a " < ul>" element and the  elements with

elements to properly structure the list item
(should always be consider as good practice ).

2. as because of the modification now the display: inline-flex; property from the .child class, as it is not necessary.

3.now removed the width: 100%; property from the .child class, as it is not needed when using justify-content: space-between;.

in the line   Test you can pass any margin as you needed or just remove it or pass 0px as if you want ...
and let me know is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Please explain the change(s) you made, and why they (might) help solve the problem. "*Try this...<block of code>*" answers don't typically do well on the site, and it's difficult for people to learn useful lessons from them.

Comment: It looks like the child still ends up in a new line. The expected result should be that the child is on the same line as the marker.